# Key-Bijective Secure Symmetric Encryption Methods

Tags: hash, aes, collision-resistance, bijection

In AES, an N-bit message is mapped 1-to-1 message-to-output (for a fixed key).
If we use a key with N bits, however, the key is not mapped 1-to-1 key-to-output
(for a fixed message).

So, is there any secure symmetric encryption method with a 1-to-1 key-to-output
mapping?

In the end, I'm just looking for a hash function h(m,k) with no collisions
over m (for a fixed k) and no collisions over k (for a fixed m), but it seems
easiest to leverage encryption methods research.

Comment: Does the number of valid ms need to equal the number of valid ks? ​ Does the number of allowed outputs need to equal the maximum of those two? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Yes and yes. Ideally, I want all N-bit numbers valid for m, all N-bit numbers valid for k, and then to simply calculate an N-bit output.  N=128 or more.

Comment: What security properties do you want? ​ (Consider [bitwise-xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR).) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: At this point, I just want the obvious: Determining k (from known m and output) takes much longer than determining output (from known m and k).  So, XOR is out.

Comment: You have a constant M. Using 2 values K1 and K2 as key to an encryption algorithm E, you get C1=E(K1,M), C2=E(K2,M) and worry about the fact that C1 could equal C2 for certain K1 and K2 that are not equal. But you could have C1'=E(M,K1), C2'=E(M,K2) and C1' and C2' are sure to be different, right? (If the particular value of M here bing used as key would be a concern, you could IMHO use in it's place M'=E(K',M) where K' is a suitable key for E.)

Comment: @Mok-Kong What you've said is all true, but I want an encryption method which is simultaneously bijective over both M and K.

Comment: But now you are considering the general relation C=f(M,K). If C, M, and K are all of  n bits and you demand bijectivity over both M and K, that wouldn't be feasible in principle (I conjecture).

Comment: What do you want this _for_?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a function $h(m, k)$ such that for fixed $m$, $k \mapsto h(m, k)$ is a permutation, and for fixed $k$, $m \mapsto h(m, k)$ is a permutation.  Obviously $m$, $k$, and the output of $h$ must be in the same space.  Suppose they live in a group $G$ (written additively), *e.g.* they're bit strings interpreted in $\operatorname{GF}(2^n)$.  For any fixed permutations $\pi$ and $\sigma$, $(m, k) \mapsto \pi(m) + \sigma(k)$ satisfies this.  (It seems likely that this is the *only* shape $h$ can have, but I haven't ruled others out.)

However, you presumably have some security goals in mind.  For example, you probably want to require that $\pi$ and $\sigma$ be difficult to invert; otherwise, a known-plaintext attack would lead to key recovery from the ciphertext $c = h(m, k)$ by $(m, c) \mapsto \sigma^{-1}(c - \pi(m))$.  One option would be $x \mapsto (g^x - 1) \bmod p$ where $p$ is a large prime and $g$ is a generator of $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$; this is a permutation of $\{0, 1, 2, \dots, p - 2\}$, inverting which is tantamount to computing discrete logs.  (One could also use $x \mapsto x^3 \bmod pq$ for large secret primes $p$ and $q$, if one wanted a permutation with a back door.)

It might help to know what you wanted to use this for!

Comment: Thanks. Looks like you have a hash but no unhash/decryption method from knowledge of the key (and if you include a back door as part of the key in your last proposal, I think we lose the 1-to-1 key-to-output requirement, right?).  It has been a long time, so I don't remember what exactly motivated my question, but I think I was just curious mathematically if 1-to-1 key-to-output decryptable methods existed.

Comment: Decryption is $(c, k) \mapsto \pi^{-1}(c - \sigma(k))$.  $x \mapsto x^3 \bmod pq$ is a permutation of the units of $\mathbb Z/(pq)\mathbb Z$ (and zero); in principle someone could pass in an input that is not a unit (or zero), but if they managed to find one, they have factored the modulus.